# isomorphism inverse with identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\phi\colon G\to H$ be an isomorphism. Show that there exists a
homomorphism $\phi^{-1}\colon H\to G$ so that
$\phi\circ\phi^{-1}=id_H$ and $\phi^{-1}\circ\phi=id_G$.

Because $\phi$ is an isomorphism I know that the order of $G = H$ So define $\phi^{-1} :H \mapsto G$ such that $\phi^{-1}(x) = y$ then $\phi^{-1}(\phi(y) = \phi^{-1}(x) = y $ and go from there correct

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism so it's bijective and then $\phi^{-1}$ exists and it's bijective. Prove that $\phi^{-1}$ is a homomorphism to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

there is only one possible value for $\phi^{-1}$ since $\phi^{-1}$ is an inverse of the function $\phi$. So we just have to check that the inverse of $\phi$(as a function) is a homomorphism (it is bijective because it is the inverse of a function).

To do this take $h_1,h_2\in H$ we have to prove $\phi^{-1}(h_1h_2)=\phi^{-1}(h_1) \phi^{-1}(h_2)$.

Of course what is the image under $\phi$ of $\phi^{-1}(h_1)\phi^{-1}(h_2)$?

It is $\phi(\phi^{-1}h_1\phi^{-1}h_2)$ and since $\phi$ is a homomorphism this is $\phi(\phi^{-1}(h_1))\phi(\phi^{-1}h_2))=h_1h_2$.

So the image under $\phi$ of $\phi^{-1}(h_1)\phi^{-1}(h_2)$ is $h_1h_2$. Hence $\phi^{-1}(h_1)\phi^{-1}(h_2)$ is the only element that maps to $h_1h_2$. Therefore $\phi^{-1}(h_1)\phi^{-1}(h_2)=\phi^{-1}(h_1h_2)$ and $\phi^{-1}$ is indeed a homorphism.